# How to get a row from Ember.js data store model (RestAdapter) without calling server?

Tags: ember.js

Function:

App.Fullquiz.find(5)

queries my server api for this record, but this record is already available in the model.

How to get this record without querying the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use

> store.getById()

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_getById

*Get a record by a given type and ID without triggering a fetch.*

Good luck